# How will inheritance is depicted in a sequence diagram?

Tags: inheritance, sequence-diagram

Say method m of class A calls method n on class B, but the source code of class B does not contain n, since n is inherited from one of the superclasses of B.

How will the sequence diagram look?

Will there be message interaction between A and B by the method n or would it be with A and the superclass of B with by method n

Comment: sequence diagram does not care about inheritance.

Comment: agree, sequence is to model object behaviour at runtime, it doesn't care about static code modeling like inheritance, since those were only distinguishable in the codes, at runtime the object that A is talking is simply B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're to respect the principle of encapsulation, the interaction would purely be between `A` and `B`.  The fact that `B`'s implementation uses inheritance is of no concern to the code written in `A` - it's sole world view is that it calls the method on `B`.

You can safely change the implementation in `B` and not affect `A`.  This is another reason to diagram the interactions this way.

Comment: I really did but it said i need to have at least 15 reputation. I only have 14 am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: No worries - I think if you wait a short while (not sure how long offhand), you can mark the answer as accepted.  It's the check mark on the left of the answer.  And welcome to SO.