# What is the sequence diagram of the constructor of a child class?

Tags: c#, sequence-diagram

If I have something like this:

```
public class A{...}
public class B:A{...}
public class C:B{...}
```

I know that if I call C constructor with no parameters, it will first call A and B constructors. But how do I represent that in a sequence diagram?

```
c = new C()
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'd argue that you shouldn't do that in the first place since it's an implementation detail of the language. A quick search indicates others agree: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364595/how-will-inheritance-is-depicted-in-a-sequence-diagram

Comment: It certainly isn't an "implementation detail", those are subject to change. The order of constructor execution is very much a fundamental specification of the language.

Comment: Why do you want to represent that detail in a sequence diagram? If you do then all you have to do is to treat it like a regular method call.

Comment: Right, in a sequence diagram the inheritance doesn't play a roll, it's just C->B->A->B->C. The first leg is passing the parameters.